# Laravel 9 request()->all() return empty data in the AppServiceProvider when testing with php artisan test

Tags: laravel, testing

As the subject the request() helper returns nothing in the app service provider when testing.

The expected result is that when a request with an exp input sent to the server, the provider will decide which FormRequest to use to do the validation, but in the test enviroment it is not possible because I don't get anything in request()->all(). It works well if not doing the testing from php artisan test.

below is the testing code sample.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Order\Request;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use App\Services\TestingModelService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class TicketRequestTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;

....
    //only the necesary ones
        $transSactionData = [
           'data'=>1,
           'user'=>123,
           'exp'=>1
        ];

        $response = $this->post('/api/order',$transSactionData);
....
}
```

Below is the AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use App\Http\Requests\MySimpleRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Http\Requests\abstract\MyFactory;
use App\Http\Requests\MyExpRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
...

   
  

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        
        if (request()->input('exp') !== null) {
            $this->app->bind(
                MyFactory::class,
                MyExpRequest::class
            );
        } else {
            $this->app->bind(
                MyFactory::class,
                MySimpleRequest::class
            );
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a closure so it isn't resolved until needed:

```php
$this->app->bind(MyFactory::class, function() {
    if (request()->input('exp') !== null) {
        return MyExpRequest::class
    } else {
        return MySimpleRequest::class
    }
});
```